# Mailing list submit in Safecracker

Tags: safecracker

I'm looking for a way to submit to a mailinglist (standard ee mailing list module) when submitting a safecracker form. Basically a user will click a checkbox "yes, send me the newsletter".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to do this out of the box with Safecracker. However, you can write an extension that responds to the [safecracker_submit_entry_start or safecracker_submit_entry_end hooks](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/development.html).

```
    $data = array(
            'class'     => 'Mailing_list_ext',
            'method'    => 'add_to_mailing_list',
            'hook'      => 'safecracker_submit_entry_end',
            'settings'  => '',
            'priority'  => '10',
            'version'   => $this->version,
            'enabled'   => 'y'
    );
    $this->EE->db->insert('extensions', $data);
```

Basically, you'll want your extension to check for the custom field you're using for the newsletter signup, then you'll have to insert your user's email address into the exp_mailing_list table:

```
function add_to_mailing_list($data) {
    if($this->EE->input->post('add_me_to_list') == 'yes') {
        //get the email address from the safecracker form
        $email = $this->EE->input->post('email');

        //either hardcode the list id from exp_mailing_lists or lookup with a query
        $list_id = 1;

        //generate the auth check
        $code = $this->EE->functions->random('alnum', 10);

        //insert a new row into exp_mailing_list

        $this->EE->db->query("INSERT INTO exp_mailing_list (list_id, authcode, email, ip_address) 
        VALUES ('".$this->EE->db->escape_str($list_id)."', '".$code."', 
        '".$this->EE->db->escape_str($email)."', 
        '".$this->EE->db->escape_str($this->EE->input->ip_address())."')");
    }
}
```

To learn more about creating EE extensions, you can view the [Extension Development docs here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html)

Comment: I should note that if you're open to using another mailing list provider, there is an excellent add-on for MailChimp and EE that will allow your users to opt-in via safecracker: http://blog.mailchimp.com/introducing-a-new-expression-enginemailchimp-integration/